# How to bind to vector<>::at?

Tags: c++, functor

In Visual C++ 2013 the following code gives me an "ambiguous call" compile error:

```
typedef vector<int> V;
V v;
auto b1 = bind(&V::at, &v);
```

Now I have searched around and found I should be casting to the signature I want. So I do this:

```
auto b2 = bind(static_cast<int(V::*)(V::size_type)>(&V::at), &v);
```

Now, the error is:

```
'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'int (__thiscall std::vector<_Ty>::* )(unsigned int)'
```

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type of `V::at` is `V::reference`:

```
auto b = std::bind(static_cast<V::reference (V::*)(V::size_type)>(&V::at), v);
```

Needless to say, this is an abomination.

Comment: Yeah, but it's logical. I just didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not required to use `bind` you could maybe use `std::function` :

```
std::function<int&(int)> b1 = [&v](int index){return v.at(index);}
```

Comment: No I cant, because I use it from C++/CLI, where local lambdas are not allowed.